# Creating unique labels in Haskell

Tags: haskell, code-generation, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler for a simple imperative language in Haskell, outputting Java bytecode. I've gotten to the point where I'm emitting an abstract representation of bytecodes.

While writing code for compiling if-statements I ran in to some trouble. To implement if-statements I need labels to jump to. Therefore I need to generate a name for that label, and that name needs to be unique.

My first thought was to thread some state through `compileStatement`, i.e

```
compileStatement :: Statement -> UniqueIDState -> [AbstractInstruction]
```

Of course, `compilerStatement` is recursive, so using this method would require me to pass the state of the unique ID generator back upp from the recursive calls:

```
compileStatement :: Statement -> UniqueIDState -> (UniqueIdState, [AbstractInstruction])
```

This seems a bit clumsy, especially if I realize I need to carry around more state in the future; is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Threading state is the sort of thing the State monad was invented for.

Comment: You've just invented the State monad :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a "unique supply". The usual way to do this in Haskell is by threading a counter through the State monad, which automates the plumbing problem you describe.

Comment: Theres [an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/New_monads/MonadSupply) on the haskell.org wiki.

Comment: This solved my problem, and the State monad (monads in general, really) seem quite elegant. I used the mtl1 instead of the current mtl2 though.

Comment: `mtl 2.*` is what is standard now. It has pretty much the same interface.

Answer (score 5):

> *I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail.*
>
> [Abraham Maslow.](https://www.quotemaster.org/qa6ae167be593b4b6ae446b6deb2277a9)

How about something different - a unique-supply that **isn't** a member of the `Monad` class. As it happens, you were almost there with your original type signature:

```
    compileStatement :: Statement -> UniqueIDState -> [AbstractInstruction]
```

If the *only* requirement is that each label is unique - no need to count how many were used, providing the same identifiers given the same circumstances, etc - there's a less-invasive technique you can use.

In [IO-free <s>spillable</s> splittable supplies](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/io-free-splittable-supply), Luke Palmer shows how [value supplies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply-0.5) can be *encapsulated*:

```
    runSupply :: (forall a . Eq a => Supply a -> b) -> b
```

This avoids having the monadic `IO` type taint large parts of the programs which use them: *nice!* But that isn't the only problem - depending on how they're defined, the onus is on you to use such supplies correctly. For example, assuming:

```
    data Statement =
        ... | If Statement Statement Statement | ...
```

then if:

```
    compileStatement (If c t e) s =
        case split s of
          s1 : s2 : s3 : _ -> buildCondJump (compileStatement c s1)
                                            (compileStatement t s2)
                                            (compileStatement e s3)
```

is mistakenly changed to:

```
    compileStatement (If c t e) s =
        case split s of
          s1 : s2 : s3 : _ -> buildCondJump (compileStatement c s)
                                            (compileStatement t s)
                                            (compileStatement e s)
```

not only are `UniqueSupply` and `Unique` values being erroneously reused, there's the potential for a space leak if any of the recursive calls to `compileStatement` uses the supply intensively.

---

Unlike [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean), Haskell has no standard way of marking types as *monousal*. That leaves checks at runtime as the only option: definitely a job for an abstract data type!

Here's a thought - if that ADT was also <s>spittable</s> splittable, we could be able to use it to define an alternate value-supply type. All going well, the values of this new type would then have both properties: <s>slippable</s> splittable and monousal.

Looking at [`Data.Supply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply-0.5/docs/Data-Supply.html) reveals the use of a binary-tree type - the module and definitions seem to be based on the following example from the functional pearl [On generating unique names], written by Lennart Augustsson, Mikael Rittri and Dan Synek - from page 4 of 7:

```
    module HideGensym(
        Name, NameSupply, initialNameSupply, getNameDeplete, splitNameSupply)
    where

        gensym :: a -> Int  -- implemented in assembler

        data Name = MkName Int deriving (Eq)
        data NameSupply = MkNameSupply Name NameSupply NameSupply

        initialNameSupply = gen ()
            where gen x = MkNameSupply (MkName (gensym x)) (gen x) (gen x)
        getNameDeplete (MkNameSupply n s1 _) = (n, s1)
        splitNameSupply (MkNameSupply _ s1 s2) = (s1, s2)
```

...`gensym`: we'll leave that one for now. Let's look at how we can insert the new ADT into `NameSupply`...after we attend to a more mundane matter: - two identical calls to `gen`- `MkNameSupply ... (gen x) (gen x)` - to an optimising Haskell implementation, they're the same value:

```
         -- same function, same argument, same result: what's the matter? 
        initialNameSupply = gen ()
            where gen x = let s = gen x in
                          MkNameSupply (MkName (gensym x)) s s
```

Then again, maybe we can solve both problems at once:

```
        initialNameSupply = runUO gen
            where gen u = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                          MkNameSupply (MkName (gensym ())) (gen u1) (gen u2)
```

where `UO` will be our new use-once split-ready abstract-data type:

```
    module UO(
        UO, initUO, splitUO, splitUO2, ...
    ) where

    data UO s ...
    runUO    :: (forall s . UO s -> a) -> a
    splitUO  :: UO s -> [UO s]
    splitUO2 :: UO s -> (UO s, UO s)   
               ⋮
```

...which can also be encapsulated.

<sub>(Surely there must be a better word than *<s>spiltable</s>* *splittable* in the English language...)</sub>

---

Now for the `gensym` problem - let's start with this cautionary remark about that `HideGensym` module, also on page 4 of 7:

> The `gensym` [thing] must be coded in assembler, and possibly also the `gen` function.

...otherwise that single call to `gensym` might be lifted all the way out: remember `gen ()`?

```
         {- WRONG! -}
        initialNameSupply = runUO gen
            where gen u = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                          MkNameSupply (MkName x) (gen u1) (gen u2)
        x = gensym ()
```

Since `gensym` (supposedly!) accepts any type of input:

```
        gensym :: a -> Int  -- implemented in assembler
```

this shouldn't break anything:

```
        initialNameSupply = runUO gen
            where gen u = let !(u1:u2:u3:_) = splitUO u in
                          MkNameSupply (MkName (gensym u1)) (gen u2) (gen u3)
```

As a bonus, we can make a slightly-more generic version of `initialNameSupply`:

```
        initialNameSupply = initialSupply gensym

        initialSupply :: (UO s -> Int) -> NameSupply
        initialSupply g = runUO gen
            where gen u = let !(u1:u2:u3:_) = splitUO u in
                          MkNameSupply (MkName (g u1)) (gen u2) (gen u3)
```

(...alright, so `gensym` is still there - at least now it's isolated.)

---

By now you've probably noticed the other example module `OneTimeSupplies`, with its own cautionary remark:

> It is referentially transparent only if each supply is used at most once.

In addition, back on page 3 of 7:

> If a compile-time analysis of a program can guarantee that every name supply is used at most once, either to do `getNameDeplete` or `splitNameSupply`, the tree becomes unnecessary [...]

Since we're relying on `UO` to provide the same guarantee, can we also go tree-free in our implementation and save some work?

To do that, `supplyValue` and the `split`s will need an upgrade:

- the simplest option for `supplyValue` is to provide it with the generator (`g` in `initialSupply`).

  ```
    data NameSupply = forall s . Supply (UO s -> Int) ...

    supplyValue :: NameSupply -> Name 
    supplyValue (Supply g ...) = MkName (g ...)
  ```
- as for the `split`s, they require an `UO` value so they can obtain the new `UO` values needed by the new supplies:

  ```
    data NameSupply = forall s . Supply (UO s) ...

    split  :: NameSupply -> [NameSupply]
    split  (Supply u ...) = [ Supply v ... |  v <- splitUO u ]

    split2 :: NameSupply -> (NameSupply, NameSupply)
    split2 (Supply u ...) = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                            (Supply u1 ..., Supply u2 ...)
  ```

That clearly suggests:

```
    data NameSupply = forall s . Supply (UO s -> Int) (UO s)

    supplyValue (Supply g u) = MkName (g u)

    split  (Supply g u) = [ Supply g v |  v <- splitUO u ]

    split2 (Supply g u) = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                          (Supply g u1, Supply g u2)
```

But does it also work for `initialNameSupply`?

```
    initialNameSupply = initialSupply gensym

    initialSupply :: (UO s -> Int) -> NameSupply
    initialSupply = runUO . Supply
```

It gets better:

```
    type NameSupply = Supply Name
    data Name = MkName Int deriving (Eq)
    initialNameSupply = initialSupply (MkName . gensym)

     --    NameSupply    --
     -- ================ --
     --      Supply      --

    data Supply a = forall s . Supply (UO s -> a) (UO s)      

    instance Functor Supply where
        fmap f (Supply g u) = Supply (f . g) u
    
    supplyValue :: Supply a -> a
    supplyValue (Supply g u) = g u

    split  :: Supply a -> [Supply a]
    split  (Supply g u) = [ Supply g v |  v <- splitUO u ]

    split2 :: Supply a -> (Supply a, Supply a)
    split2 (Supply g u) = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                          (Supply g u1, Supply g u2)

    initialSupply :: (UO s -> a) -> NameSupply
    initialSupply = runUO . Supply
```

This is *very* promising, **if** `UO` and associates can be defined as intended...

---

If you've read [the post](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/io-free-splittable-supply) by Luke Palmer, you already know that he uses an <s>`ugly`</s> `unsafe` entity to define `runSupply`.  Well, right now (2022 Jan) `runST` is defined [in similar fashion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.ST.html#runST):

```
    runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
    runST (ST st_rep) = case runRW# st_rep of (# _, a #) -> a
```

where:

```
    newtype ST s a = ST (STRep s a)
    type STRep s a = State# s -> (# State# s, a #
    runRW# :: STRep RealWorld a -> (# State# RealWorld, a #)
```

Can `UO` be defined without resorting to such measures? That's probably worthy of a separate answer - for now, we'll just tolerate the ugliness:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, RankNTypes, UnboxedTuples, MagicHash #-}
    module UO(
        UO, runUO, splitUO, splitUO2,
        useUO, asUO,
    ) where

    import Prelude   (String, Eq(..))
    import Prelude   ((.), ($), (++), error, all)
    import Data.Char (isSpace)
    import GHC.Base  (State#, MutVar#)
    import GHC.Base  (runRW#, newMutVar#, noDuplicate#)
    import GHC.Exts  (atomicModifyMutVar#)
    import GHC.ST    (ST(..), STRep)

    data UO s               =  UO (UO# s)

    runUO                   :: (forall s . UO s -> a) -> a
    runUO g                 =  let (# _, r #) = runRW# (useUO# (g . UO)) in r

    splitUO                 :: UO s -> [UO s]
    splitUO u               =  let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in u1 : splitUO u

    splitUO2                :: UO s -> (UO s, UO s)
    splitUO2 (UO h)         =  let (# h1, h2 #) = splitUO2# h in (UO h1, UO h2)

    useUO                   :: (UO s -> a) -> ST s a
    useUO g                 =  ST (\s -> useUO# (g . UO) s)

    asUO                    :: Eq a => String -> ST s a -> UO s -> a
    asUO name (ST act) (UO h)
                            =  asUO# name act h

     -- local definitions --
    type UO# s              =  String -> State# s

    splitUO2#               :: UO# s -> (# UO# s, UO# s #)
    splitUO2# h             =  let !s           = h "splitUO2"
                                   (# s', h1 #) = dispense# s
                                   (# _,  h2 #) = dispense# s'
                               in  (# h1, h2 #)

    useUO#                  :: (UO# s -> a) -> STRep s a
    useUO# g s              =  let (# s', h #) = dispense# s
                                   !r           = g h
                               in  (# s', r #)

    dispense#               :: STRep s (UO# s)
    dispense# s             =  let (# s', r #) = newMutVar# () s
                               in  (# s', expire# s' r #)

    expire#                 :: State# s -> MutVar# s () -> String -> State# s
    expire# s r name        =  let (# s', () #) = atomicModifyMutVar# r use s
                               in  s'
                               where
                                   use x   =  (error nowUsed, x)
                                   nowUsed =  name' ++ ": already expired"
                                   name'   =  if all isSpace name then "(unknown)"
                                              else name

    asUO#                   :: Eq a => String -> STRep s a -> UO# s -> a
    asUO# name act h        =  let (# _, t #) = act (noDuplicate# (h name)) in t
```

It's a little more complicated than strictly necessary (e.g. rudimentary reuse-error reporting) but in exchange for that, `UO`-based definitions can now manipulate local state...

---

There's one other definition in [`Data.Supply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply-0.5/docs/Data-Supply.html) to implement:

```
    newSupply :: a -> (a -> a) -> IO (Supply a)
    newSupply start next = gen =<< newIORef start
      where gen r = unsafeInterleaveIO
                  $ do v  <- unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
                       ls <- gen r
                       rs <- gen r
                       return (Node v ls rs)
            upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
```

as it would end the need for `gensym`. It is vaguely similar to `initialSupply` - can that be made more apparent?

- `gen` in the original `initialNameSupply` doesn't have a reference parameter `r`:

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen = unsafeInterleaveIO $
                                          do v  <- unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
                                             ls <- gen
                                             rs <- gen
                                             return (Node v ls rs)
                                gen
        where upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
  ```
- the value-action `unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)` performs the role of `gensym` in the original `initialNameSupply`:

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen    = unsafeInterleaveIO $
                                             do v  <- genval
                                                ls <- gen
                                                rs <- gen
                                                return (Node v ls rs)
                                    genval = unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
                                gen
        where upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
  ```
- `gen` in the original `initialNameSupply` had no need of `do`-notation:

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen    = unsafeInterleaveIO (liftM3 Node genval gen gen)
                                    genval = unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
                                gen
        where upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
  ```
- does `genval` have to be in that `let`-binding?

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen = unsafeInterleaveIO (liftM3 Node (genval r) gen gen)
                                gen
        where genval r = unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
              upd a    = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
  ```
- `upd` is only used in `genval`:

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen = unsafeInterleaveIO (liftM3 Node (genval r) gen gen)
                                gen
        where genval r = let upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
                         in unsafeInterleaveIO (atomicModifyIORef r upd)
  ```
- can some content in `genval` be moved to a separate definition?

  ```
      newSupply start next = do r <- newIORef start
                                let gen = unsafeInterleaveIO (liftM3 Node (genval r) gen gen)
                                gen
        where genval r = unsafeInterleaveIO (nextValue r next)

      nextValue :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO a
      nextValue r next = let upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
                         in atomicModifyIORef r upd
  ```

---

Now that it more clearly resembles the original `initialNameSupply`, re-implementing `newSupply` using our new `Supply` type is relatively simple - first, a change of monadic type:

```
    newSupply start next = do r <- newSTRef start
                              let gen = unsafeInterleaveST (liftM3 Node (genval r) gen gen)
                              gen
      where genval r = unsafeInterleaveST (nextValue r next)

    nextValue :: STRef s a -> (a -> a) -> ST s a
    nextValue r next = let upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
                       in atomicModifyST r upd
```

No other changes are needed for `nextValue`. As for `newSupply`:

```
    newSupply :: Eq a => a -> (a -> a) -> ST s (Supply a)
    newSupply start next = do r <- newSTRef start
                              let g = asUO "genval" (genval r)
                              useUO (Supply g)
      where genval r = nextValue r next
```

which can then be used to define our version of `runSupply`:

```
    runSupply :: (forall a . Eq a => Supply a -> b) -> b
    runSupply f = f (runST (newSupply (0 :: Int) succ))
```

Can we now, finally, expel `gensym` from the `NameSupply` type?

```
    initialNameSupply :: NameSupply
    initialNameSupply = fmap MkName (initialSupply 0 succ)

    initialSupply :: Eq a => a -> (a -> a) -> Supply a
    initialSupply start next = runST (newSupply start next)
```

**Yes.**

---

Here are all the pertinent definitions, arranged into modules:

- `ExpelGensym`, the replacement for `HideGensym` on page 4 of 7:

  ```
    {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
    module ExpelGensym(
        Name, NameSupply, initialNameSupply, getNameDeplete, splitNameSupply
    ) where
    import Control.Monad    (liftM)
    import Control.Monad.ST (runST)
    import Supply           (Supply, newSupply, supplyValue, split2)

    data Name = MkName Int deriving (Eq)
    type NameSupply = Supply Name

    initialNameSupply :: Supply Name
    initialNameSupply = fmap MkName (initialSupply 0 succ)

    getNameDeplete :: NameSupply -> (Name, NameSupply)    
    getNameDeplete s = let !(s1, s2) = split2 s in (supplyValue s1, s2)

    splitNameSupply :: NameSupply -> (NameSupply, NameSupply)
    splitNameSupply = split2

     -- local definitions --
    initialSupply :: Eq a => a -> (a -> a) -> Supply a
    initialSupply start next = runST (newSupply start next)
  ```
- `Supply`, our miniature implementation of [`Data.Supply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply-0.5/docs/Data-Supply.html):

  ```
    {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes #-}
    module Supply(
        Supply, newSupply, runSupply, supplyValue, split, split2
    ) where
    import Control.Monad.ST
    import Data.STRef
    import UO

    data Supply a = forall s . Supply (UO s -> a) (UO s)      

    instance Functor Supply where
        fmap f (Supply g u) = Supply (f . g) u

    newSupply :: Eq a => a -> (a -> a) -> ST s (Supply a)
    newSupply start next = do r <- newSTRef start
                              let g = asUO "genval" (genval r)
                              useUO (Supply g)
      where genval r = nextValue r next

    runSupply :: (forall a . Eq a => Supply a -> b) -> b
    runSupply f = f (runST (newSupply (0 :: Int) succ))

    supplyValue :: Supply a -> a
    supplyValue (Supply g u) = g u

    split  :: Supply a -> [Supply a]
    split  (Supply g u) = [ Supply g v |  v <- splitUO u ]

    split2 :: Supply a -> (Supply a, Supply a)
    split2 (Supply g u) = let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in
                          (Supply g u1, Supply g u2)

     -- local definitions --
    nextValue :: STRef s a -> (a -> a) -> ST s a
    nextValue r next = let upd a = let b = next a in seq b (b, a)
                       in atomicModifySTRef r upd

    {-
     -- if your Haskell installation doesn't define it --
    atomicModifySTRef :: STRef s a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> ST s b
    atomicModifySTRef r f = do x <- readSTRef r
                               let !(x', y) = f x
                               writeSTRef r x'
                               return y
    -}
  ```
- `UO`, that use-once split-ready abstract-data type:

  ```
    {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, RankNTypes, UnboxedTuples, MagicHash #-}
    module UO(
        UO, runUO, splitUO, splitUO2,
        useUO, asUO,
    ) where

    import Prelude   (String, Eq(..))
    import Prelude   ((.), ($), (++), error, all)
    import Data.Char (isSpace)
    import GHC.Base  (State#, MutVar#)
    import GHC.Base  (runRW#, newMutVar#, noDuplicate#)
    import GHC.Exts  (atomicModifyMutVar#)
    import GHC.ST    (ST(..), STRep)

    data UO s               =  UO (UO# s)

    runUO                   :: (forall s . UO s -> a) -> a
    runUO g                 =  let (# _, r #) = runRW# (useUO# (g . UO)) in r

    splitUO                 :: UO s -> [UO s]
    splitUO u               =  let !(u1, u2) = splitUO2 u in u1 : splitUO u

    splitUO2                :: UO s -> (UO s, UO s)
    splitUO2 (UO h)         =  let (# h1, h2 #) = splitUO2# h in (UO h1, UO h2)

    useUO                   :: (UO s -> a) -> ST s a
    useUO g                 =  ST (\s -> useUO# (g . UO) s)

    asUO                    :: Eq a => String -> ST s a -> UO s -> a
    asUO name (ST act) (UO h)
                            =  asUO# name act h

     -- local definitions --
    type UO# s              =  String -> State# s

    splitUO2#               :: UO# s -> (# UO# s, UO# s #)
    splitUO2# h             =  let !s           = h "splitUO2"
                                   (# s', h1 #) = dispense# s
                                   (# _,  h2 #) = dispense# s'
                               in  (# h1, h2 #)

    useUO#                  :: (UO# s -> a) -> STRep s a
    useUO# g s              =  let (# s', h #) = dispense# s
                                   !r           = g h
                               in  (# s', r #)

    dispense#               :: STRep s (UO# s)
    dispense# s             =  let (# s', r #) = newMutVar# () s
                               in  (# s', expire# s' r #)

    expire#                 :: State# s -> MutVar# s () -> String -> State# s
    expire# s r name        =  let (# s', () #) = atomicModifyMutVar# r use s
                               in  s'
                               where
                                   use x   =  (error nowUsed, x)
                                   nowUsed =  name' ++ ": already expired"
                                   name'   =  if all isSpace name then "(unknown)"
                                              else name

    asUO#                   :: Eq a => String -> STRep s a -> UO# s -> a
    asUO# name act h        =  let (# _, t #) = act (noDuplicate# (h name)) in t
  ```