# Writing an assembler in Haskell - mapM with state?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing a very simple two-pass assembler in Haskell and I've come across a scenario that I don't yet have the experience to solve. I think the solution is likely to involve monad transformers, which I don't really understand.

The assembler parses the assembly code into a list of `Statement`s, which are either instructions or labels. Some `Statement`s may refer to labels. The assembler needs to convert the `Statement`s into `Instruction`s, which involves eliminating the labels and substituting the label references with an appropriate value.

I have written the first pass of the assembler, which produces a `[(String, Int)]` representing a map from labels to addresses. I have also written the following function for translating a `Statement` into an `Instruction`:

```haskell
stmtToInstruction :: Int -> [(String, Int)] -> Statement -> Either String [I.Instruction]
stmtToInstruction addr labels stmt = case stmt of
    ADD d s1 s2     -> Right [I.ADD d s1 s2]
    BEQL s1 s2 l    -> case do label <- find (\e -> fst e == l) labels
                               let labelAddr = snd label
                               let relativeAddr = I.ImmS $ fromIntegral (labelAddr - addr)
                               return (I.BEQ s1 s2 relativeAddr) of
                        Just i -> Right [i]
                        Nothing -> Left $ "Label " ++ l ++ " not defined"
    LABEL _         -> Right []
```

I've omitted several cases for brevity, but you can see all the possible results here:

- `ADD` always succeeds and produces an instruction
- `BEQL` can either succeed or fail, depending on whether a label is found
- `LABEL` always succeeds, even though it produces no actual instructions

This works as expected. The problem I now have is writing this function:

```haskell
replaceLabels :: [Statement] -> Either String [I.Instruction]
```

`replaceLabels` takes a list of statements, and runs `stmtToInstruction` on each one. The `addr` argument to `stmtToInstruction` must be the length of the `[Instruction]` accumulated so far. The output may either be a `Left String`, if one of the label references was invalid, or a `Right [I.Instruction]`, if there were no errors.

`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` gets us some of the way there, but provides no way to inject the current address into the `(a -> m b)` function. How do I make this work?

Comment: You can do this in one pass using laziness - tie the knot using a map.

Comment: @Alec can you point to me to any resources on this approach?

Comment: `foldM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b ` looks closer to me: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM

Comment: http://bobkonf.de/2016/breitner-monaden.html is a resource, albeit in German.
http://wall.org/~lewis/2013/10/15/asm-monad.html is an English one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell labelling items in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876135/haskell-labelling-items-in-recursive-function)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, that looks clever, general, and friendly to write, but a bit tricky to debug if something goes wrong. An alternative explicit approach would be to transform a stream of statements into a stream of instructions statefully, using a map from labels to addresses and a FIFO queue of non-label statements headed by a branch to an unknown label. Another option might be to play linker and keep track of branches that need to be patched up (map from unseen labels to branches that reference them). Not very pretty, but I imagine it might be more efficient in some contexts.

Answer (score 4):

You're right: the `StateT` monad transformer will do the trick:

```
imapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m)
          => (Int -> a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
imapM f = flip runStateT 0 .
  mapM (\a ->
    do
      count <- get
      put $! count + 1
      f count a)
```

But writing the specialized version for lists might be better:

```
itraverse :: Applicative f
          => (Int -> a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
itraverse f = go 0 where
  go !_ [] = pure []
  go !count (x:xs) = (:) <$> f count x <*> go (count + 1) xs
```

Comment: You could also implement that `itraverse` using `zipWithM f [0..]`

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a recursive solution that I'm sure is very inefficient. I'd still be interested to see the 'proper' way of doing this.

```haskell
replaceLabels :: [Statement] -> Either String [I.Instruction]
replaceLabels [] = Right []
replaceLabels stmts@(s:ss) = replaceLabels' labels stmts 0
    where labels = process stmts

replaceLabels' :: [(String, Int)] -> [Statement] -> Int -> Either String [I.Instruction]
replaceLabels' _ [] _ = Right []
replaceLabels' labels (s:ss) addr = do
                                instructions <- stmtToInstruction addr labels s
                                restInstructions <- replaceLabels' labels ss (addr + length instructions)
                                return (instructions ++ restInstructions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing

```
stmtToInstruction :: Int -> [(String, Int)] -> Statement -> Either String [I.Instruction]
```

into

```
stmtToInstruction :: [(String, Int)] -> Statement -> Either String (Int -> [I.Instruction])
```

That is, moving the function that takes the address into the `Right` branch of the `Either`. The reason is that label reference errors seem to be independent of addresses, so it's better to handle reference errors first and then worry about the address stuff in isolation.

This function resolves the references:

```
resolveRefs :: [(String,Int)] -> [Statement] -> Either String [Int -> [Instruction]]
resolveRefs environment = traverse (stmtToInstruction environment)
```

[(`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) is equivalent to `mapM` but it only requires an `Applicative` constraint. They are different functions merely for historical reasons.)

Ok, after having handled the errors, lets now focus on the `[Int -> [Instruction]]` list. It seems that we have to map over it from the left while carrying an accumulated address that we must supply to each function. The [`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) function is perfect for this:

```
resolveAddrs ::  [Int -> [Instruction]] -> [Instruction]
resolveAddrs funcs = mconcat . snd $ accumulate funcs
    where
    accumulate :: [Int -> [Instruction]] -> (Int,[[Instruction]])
    accumulate = mapAccumL step 0
    step address func = let is = func address in (address + length is,is)
```