# How can I generate random numbers in Haskell without IO in a range?

Tags: haskell, random

I would like to generate random numbers in a range and the type signature to be `Int -> Int`. I've read multiple other posts but none of them suggested ways to return a type `Int`. I used `System.IO.Unsafe` in my code but it is not recommended to do so. Here's my code:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

-- random number generator
rng :: Int -> Int
rng upper = unsafePerformIO $ randomRIO (0,upper-1)
```

Does anyone have any suggests on how to generate random Int in a range in Haskell?

Edit: It might be impossible to change `IO Int -> Int` so I converted my code to

```
-- random number generator
rng :: Int -> IO Int
rng upper = randomRIO (0,upper-1)
```

The reason why I need a rng is because I want to get random numbers within the range length of the list to get an index for an element of a list.

`list !! rng (length list)` but I'm getting the error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘IO Int’` which is expected.

It's not a duplicate because 1. I want values in a range, 2. my rng does not return the same values. I'm new to Haskell and I don't know how to manipulate Monads. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't sensibly make it `Int -> Int`. The closest you can get and still behave sensibly is `Int -> StdGen -> (StdGen, Int)`; this type may be implemented using `randomR` rather than `randomRIO`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate different random values in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836652/how-can-i-generate-different-random-values-in-haskell)

Comment: `rng x = fst $ randomR (0, x-1) $ makeStdGen $ length "https://xkcd.com/221"` :P

Comment: You do not need to involve IO, but because of Haskell _referential transparency_ you cannot have that  `Int -> Int` type signature. [See here for a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890878/11282404).

Comment: You can also use the techniques mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311512 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I the spirit of https://xkcd.com/221/, here's a “solution” without any IO:

```
rng :: Int -> Int
rng upper
 | upper<=4   = upper
 | otherwise  = 4
```

So that gives you an “RFC 1149.5 compliant random number”. It's always four, unless that is outside the range.

What's the problem with this? Well, clearly it gives always *the same number* – and so *it must be*, because all Haskell functions must be [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), i.e. [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). OTOH, a random number *generator* is supposed to give *different* number each time you call it... it is thus *not* a function, and most other programming languages merely pretend it is a function *with side-effect* – because they have no proper means to express what side-effects are. Well, Haskell does have a proper means of expressing that, and it is the IO monad: you can have computations that depend on a side effect, but clearly these computations if you run them will then have that side-effect themselves.
In that light, the signature `Int -> IO Int` does make sense for the function. (This *is* a function, but the result is an *IO action* and only *executing* that action gives you an `Int`.)

What's ugly about that is that `IO Int` could literally do *anything* in `IO` – it could, for instance, [launch some missiles](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles-0.3/docs/Acme-Missiles.html) and give you back the number of casualities. More realistically, it could easily modify some file in you home directory. Whereas what you want is actually just a teeny tiny harmless side-effect, just enough to produce a new random number the next time. Usually, random number generators are anyways not really random but [PRNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which keep a constant-size *state variable* that is updated in a random-looking way each time you pull a value. The next time, this state will be different and thus you get a different value, as desired. This state variable *could* be held in an `IO`-mutable location

```
import Data.IORef

type RandStV = Int
type RandSt = IORef RandStV

rng' :: RandSt -> Int -> IO Int
rng' rSt upper = do
   x <- readIORef rSt
   let x' = ((x * 1103515245) + 12345) `mod` 0x7fffffff -- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.26#l362
   writeIORef rSt x'
   return $ x `mod` upper
```

...or, you could just explicitly pass the updated state along with the result

```
rng'' :: Int -> RandStV -> (RandStV, Int)
rng'' upper x =
   let x' = ((x * 1103515245) + 12345) `mod` 0x7fffffff
   in (x', x `mod` upper)
```

...or it could be passed around in a dedicated [state monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State), which is just another way of writing the passing-on of an updated variable:

```
type RandStM = State RandStV

rng''' :: Int -> RandStM Int
rng''' upper = do
   x <- get
   let x' = ((x * 1103515245) + 12345) `mod` 0x7fffffff
   put x'
   return $ x `mod` upper
```

See [the random-fu package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu) for useful helpers on such a *random monad*.

One mathematical way to interpret `rng'''` is to say it is a function that takes an upper bound as the argument and gives you back a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) of numbers. The distribution is always the same, but it “contains” many numbers together with the probability of them occuring. Actually *generating* an integer means you're *sampling* from the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell was not built to generate random numbers without using `IO`.

Your example, `list !! rng (length list)`, doesn't work because `rng` returns `IO Int` and `!!` expects a `Int`.

Here is a function that uses your `rng` function to get a random element from a list:

```
-- Will crash on empty list
randomElementFromList :: [a] -> IO a
randomElementFromList list = do
  r <- rng (length list)
  return $ list !! r
```

Comment: No reason to specify this down to `[Int]`. `randomElementFromList :: [a] -> IO a`

Comment: And of course the pattern `do { x <- m; return (f x) }` is equivalent to `fmap f m` / `f <$> m`, e.g.: `(list !!) <$> rng (length list)`. When I was learning Haskell, picking up these patterns helped me understand the functor/applicative/monad operators, as “abbreviations” of patterns in `do` notation (or, in another sense, just different kinds of application and composition).